# Pass File as part of complex object to WEB API

Tags: c#, angularjs, file, asp.net-web-api, file-upload

I am using angular and kendo to upload files. When i submit to WEB API controller. I wish to submit an object eg.

```
[{
 Id : 1,
 Title : "test",
 FileList : [File1, File2]
}]
```

When I have try to convert it into my custom class on server side i.e.

```
public class MyClass 
{
   public int Id {get; set;}
   public string Title {get; set;}
   public HttpFileCollection FileList {get; set;}
}
```

All i see is empty FileList property. Is there a way to pass data in the above way to WEB API from angular?

If no, can I atleast pass a list of files with custom attributes on them like the id, title part of the title and I can treat it as a multipartdata on my web api.